# Can I use my bootloader-locked phone with a different network?

Tags: sim-unlocking, bootloader-lock

I just bought an Xperia Z and the bootloader is locked. Do I need to unlock it in order to run it on a new SIM card and can I switch to Virgin? It's OK if I can't: I will just buy a Bell SIM for $10, but will the phone be able to be switched to Bell pay as you go? It was previously on the prev. owner plan with Bell.

Answer (score 2):

The bootloader being locked has nothing to do with whether it's SIM-locked to a particular network. It just means you can't flash a custom ROM to the device (without unlocking the bootloader). You don't need to unlock the bootloader to change SIM to a different network, but if it's SIM-locked to a particular network, you need to unlock it from that network.

Whether you can switch to a PAYG SIM is entirely up to the carrier, and nothing to do with Android. You should check with the carrier.